# Search a string into a memory process using a REGEX search. Is it possible?

Tags: c++, regex, memory

Hello so basically I create a small software (anti cheat) on a game and the problem is that some cheat have regular log and not string like "cheat" "aimbot" etc.

So to resolve this problem I need to perform a regex search inside a buffer in a loop. I search lot of time for this and never found something about it but now I need this.

```
HANDLE process;
SIZE_T bytes_read;
PROCESSENTRY32 processEntry = { 0 };
MODULEENTRY32 me32{ sizeof(MODULEENTRY32) };
DWORD pid = -1;

HANDLE snapShot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);
if (snapShot == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
{
    exit(-1);
}
        
processEntry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
if (Process32First(snapShot, &processEntry))
{
    do
    {
        if (_stricmp(processEntry.szExeFile, appName.c_str()) == 0)
        {
            CloseHandle(snapShot);
            pid = processEntry.th32ProcessID;
            break;
        }
    } while (Process32Next(snapShot, &processEntry));
}

if (pid == -1)
{
    exit(-1);
}

HANDLE snapModule = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPMODULE, pid);
if (!snapModule || !::Module32First(snapModule, &me32))
{
    ::CloseHandle(snapModule);
}

process = OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, pid);
if (!process)
{
    exit(-1);
}

char* p = 0;
std::vector<char> buffer(BUFFER_SIZE);
char* displayBuffer = new char[max_char];

while (p < (char*)(_MAX_VALUE))
{
    ReadProcessMemory(process, (LPVOID)p, &buffer[0], BUFFER_SIZE, &bytes_read);

    for (auto pos = buffer.begin(); buffer.end() != (pos = std::search(pos, buffer.end(), pattern.begin(), pattern.end())); ++pos)
    {
        std::string s(pos, pos + max_char);
        stripUnicode(s);
        send_result(s);
        std::cout << s << std::endl;
        Sleep(10);
    };

    p += BUFFER_SIZE;
}

delete displayBuffer;
```

I need to have the **SAME CODE** but using a regex search.

Comment: C++ has built-in regex features. Have you looked at the [`<regex>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) library yet, such as [`std::regex_search()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) and [`std::regex_match()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match)?

Comment: Why are you mixing `std::vector<char>` with `new char[]`? You are not even using your `displayBuffer` for anything (and you are not freeing it correctly). You are also not validating whether `ReadProcessMemory()` is successful, and worse you are accessing arbitrary random memory addresses that you should not be accessing (like `0`), which can cause all hell for the target process if you accidentally trigger page faults, etc.

Comment: Why did you tag this `c` when it's clearly C++?

Comment: I already look for the regex match I just need to loop at the end of the code and replace std::search by std::regex_search